# Nest vectors consumes to much memory in c++

Tags: c++, vector, nested, memory-consumption

I`m trying to figure out why my application consumes too much memory. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <random>

typedef unsigned __int32 uint;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<uint>> arr(65536 * 16, vector<uint>());
    mt19937 mt;
    mt.seed(time(NULL));
    uniform_int<uint> generator(0, arr.size() - 1);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            uint bucketIndex = generator(mt);
            arr[bucketIndex].push_back(i);
        }
    }

    uint cap = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cap += sizeof(uint) * arr[i].capacity() + sizeof(arr[i]);
    }
    cap += sizeof(vector<uint>) * arr.capacity() + sizeof(vector<vector<uint>>);
    cout << "Total bytes: " << cap << endl;
    cout << "Press any key..." << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

I use Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio 2010, code is also compiled as 64-bit.

Code outputs the following in Debug and Release

**Total bytes: 914591424**

Looks correct (you can check it by hand), but memory manager shows that application consumes ~ **1.4 gigabytes of RAM**.

Where did those 500 megabytes came from? Could you please give me an idea how to sort this out?

**UPDATE**

Problem is caused by memory fragmentation. Can be solved by compacting memory from time to time.

Comment: Unfortunately, i didn`t find answer to my question there.

Comment: @tinnulion I think you need to look closer. Also, look at the reserved set (virtual memory is funny).

Comment: Sorry, I did`t get it. Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: Your code doesn't nearly compile. It's missing headers and using non-existent classes. It uses non-portable main. It's lacking the using namespace to make it work. Basically, "wat".

Comment: 10,000,000*16*4 == 640,000,000 Why are you surprised about the 500 megs?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I missed a piece. I`ve fixed it now.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I surprised because application should consume ~ 900 megabytes (I summed all capacities of all vectors in my code), but actually it consumes 1.4 gigabytes. There are 500 megabytes I surprised about.

Comment: @tinnulion: That is caused by fragmentation. When you fill up your vectors they storage is reallocated many times. Often when a vector needs a larger memory area its contents must be copied to another place where there is enough continuous mem region but this leaves a hole on the original place. Heavy reallocations in a continuously running program usually cause at least 2x or more memory consumption than the effectively used memory area. This can often be aided by using specialized allocators. With a general purpose allocator your extra memory consumption isn't surprising.

Comment: @tinnulion: How important is the effective memory usage for you? Do you have something to sacrifice for effective memory usage? For example extra cpu time or double memory just for the time of the initialization of the array? If you have one of these then I can show you a better solution.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I thought about fragmentation, but believed that it cannot cost 60% of memory. Due to randomization inner vectors should have just about the same size at the same moment, and reallocations should take place at the same moment. So, large ammount of memory will be free again and can be occupyied by new (larger) vectors.

Comment: Maybe not, in general case if a program allocates random sized chunks and random times then fragmentation usually casues 2x or more memory consumption.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Memory usage is the most important point. I need to store a lot of data, it doesn`t fit my 16GB memory at the moment. I can sacrifice initialization time freely, but I cannot slower access to the structure. If you have better solution - I would be thankful for it.

Comment: @tinnulion A possible solution in my answer if your goal is compacting memory. No pain, no gain.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Yeah, but memory compacting algorithm is pain itself, I think. Is there any container that has it implemented?

Comment: @tinnulion "Compacting" in the way you are thinking about it isn't possible. You have to do compacting yourself cleverly by preallocating the well-sized memory chunks. If you can not do that then you will pay with fragmentation and inefficient memory use.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I think you can. C++11 introduced `shrink_to_fit`. Boost containers has it for c++03 as well. See my answer.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I realize that I have to do it by myself. I cannot preallocate memory chunks, because I don`t know their sizes. I asked if there are some "vector<vector<>>" container which ALREADY HAS memory compacting in it.

Comment: @tinnulion There is no such data structure (in std) but one can be written for sure.

Comment: @sehe That leaves memory fragmented. Depending on the allocator it may show up the gaps between your chunks as free but holes are often just "cheap" memory that can not be used for larger allocations and filling your later allocations into gaps far from each other usually case a lot of cache misses by screwing up locality. If it comes to efficient memory usage then compact structures and memory pools are winner.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I don`t care about cache misses so much.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I'm aware of that. Of course "screwing up cache misses" isn't very fair, since having fixed layout would have considerable spread in locality. As soon as you are worrying about relative locality of otherwise contiguous datastructures, I'm sure this entire question is a topic far far left behind.

Answer (score 2):

This is because each vector contains three pointers (or their moral and size equivalent): begin, begin + size, and begin + capacity.  So when you have a vector containing tons of other small vectors, each inner vector wastes three words (so 24 bytes on a 64-bit system).

And since each inner vector's begin() points to a separate allocation, you have N times the allocation overhead cost to pay.  That could be another several bytes.

Instead, you probably want to allocate a single large region and treat it like a 2D array.  Or use one of the many libraries that offer such functionality.  That won't work if your inner vectors are of different sizes, but often they are all one size, so you really want a 2D "rectangle" anyway, rather than a vector of vectors.

Comment: I`m aware about memory overhead when using vector<vector<>> but I have to use it.

Comment: Actually my answer is about something else. Look at the code. It summarizes all capacities of all vectors. This amount of memory application have to consume. But it consumes much more!

Comment: I added the second paragraph about the memory allocation overhead.  That's where some of it is coming from for sure.  Maybe all of it--depends on the platform and the environment when you run it.  As for why you "have to" use this suboptimal solution, well, if so, don't complain when it is suboptimal.  :)

Comment: On a 64 bit system it's 24 megabypes of wasted memory on a continuous memory area without fragmentation. On a 32 bit system its only half of that. This is not the cause of the wasted hundreds of megabytes. Frequent reallocation is often much more expensive than "several bytes" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've compared with Boost Container's vector. And added `shrink_to_fit`. The difference:

```
Total bytes: 690331672    // boost::container::vector::shrink_to_fit()
Total bytes: 1120033816   // std::vector
```

(Note also that boost containers never dynamically allocate on default construction.)

Here's the code (not much change, there):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

using boost::container::vector;
using boost::optional;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<uint32_t>> arr(1<<20);
    std::mt19937 mt;
    mt.seed(time(NULL));

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> generator(0, arr.size() - 1);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            auto& bucket = arr[generator(mt)];
            //if (!bucket) bucket = vector<uint32_t>();

            bucket.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for(auto& i : arr)
        i.shrink_to_fit();

    uint32_t cap = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cap += sizeof(uint32_t) * arr[i].capacity() + sizeof(arr[i]);
    }
    cap += sizeof(vector<uint32_t>) * arr.capacity() + sizeof(arr);
    std::cout << "Total bytes: " << cap << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Update** memory profile run

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./test
Massif arguments:   (none)
ms_print arguments: massif.out.4193
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    MB
822.7^                                                                      # 
     |                                                                    @@# 
     |                                                                  @@@@#:
     |                                                                @@@@@@#:
     |                                                              @@@@@@@@#:
     |                                                          :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                                   :::::@@:@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                                 @@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                              @@@@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                            @@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                        :::@@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                   @@@:::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                                @@@@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                             @@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                         @@@:@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                     @@@@@@ :@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |                   @@@@ @@@ :@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |               @@@@@@@@ @@@ :@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     |        :::::::@@ @@@@@ @@@ :@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
     | ::@:@:::: ::: @@ @@@@@ @@@ :@@@@ @@@ :::: @@@@ @@@:: ::@ :@@@@@@@@@@@#:
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Gi
     0                                                                   69.85
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that`s true because `shrink_to_fit` descreases capacities of all containers. Can you tell how much memory consumes this code (via some sort of memory manager)?

Comment: Updated the answer with some profiling data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I`ll try boost vector and see if it helps.